# Write results to file instead of writing to Active Directory live environment

Tags: powershell, logging, export-to-csv

I need to output what this script will do before actually running it in the production environment.  Can someone please help?

All it is doing is updating the attribute EmployeeID in the user objects.  My manager wants aprint out of what values all 3500 employees would get in AD without actually writing to it. I hope this makes sense.

My CSV file:

```
employeeid,Name
9089809890,ktest
```

Script:

```
$stuff = Import-Csv c:\temp\finalexport_test.txt
$stuff

$empid = $stuff.employeeid
$userid = $stuff.name

foreach ($user in $userid) {
    Set-ADUser -Identity $user -EmployeeID $empid
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `-whatif` flag on the `Set-AdUser` cmdlet together with Transcript:

```
$stuff = Import-Csv c:\temp\finalexport_test.txt
$stuff

$empid = $stuff.employeeid
$userid = $stuff.name

foreach ($user in $userid) {
    Start-Transcript 'yourFile'
    Set-ADUser -Identity $user -EmployeeID $empid -whatif
    Stop-Transcript
    }
```